# Draft / Publish Status

Tags: database

I have two related tables. Each table has an is_publish property, for example:

```
Customer (C) 1 ... n with Order (O) (C 1--->N O)
```

if the customer is changed is_publish status to false (draft), from your point of view (technically), is the order that has a relationship with that customer also invalid or does the order have to be draft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal point of view, the order should be retained, because this is an important transaction proof.

I think a very simple example is actually a shopping mall. You can use products instead of customers to think about it.

How does the shopping mall do it?

1. Unless the user deletes it, the order information is retained.
2. Even when no order is generated, as long as an item is added to the cart, it will not be actively removed. It just reminds you that the item has expired.
3. The most important point is that if the transaction has been established, there is no such thing as invalidation. You can only initiate a cancellation request.

Comment: ooh i see, when I make an order report every month (for example), I will give a small note in the order report that the customer has become a draft and continues the report. Thanks PsiACE...